# How to loop through JSON/API data inside a component template with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I've got a functioning snippet rending a list of songs here: https://jsfiddle.net/jeremypbeasley/guraav4r/8/

```
var apiURL = "https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.gettoptracks&user=thisisheroic&period=7day&limit=6&api_key=3cbc1a3aa903935d08223263bcc3ba0b&format=json";

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    commits: null
  },
  created: function () {
    this.fetchData()
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData: function () {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
      var self = this
      xhr.open('GET', apiURL)
      xhr.onload = function () {
        self.commits = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
      }
      xhr.send()
    }
  }
})
```

html:

```
<div id="demo">
  <h1>Tracks</h1>
  <li v-for="mytrack in commits.toptracks.track">
      {{mytrack.name}}
  </li>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I attempt to use this same general method in the context of a component, it breaks and logs two errors:

First: `[Vue warn]: The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions.` and another telling me that `commits.toptracks` is undefined.

My failed attempt:

```
Vue.component('manage-posts', {
  template: '#manage-template',
  data: {
    commits: null,
  },
  created: function () {
    this.fetchData()
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData: function () {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
      xhr.open('GET', apiURL)
      xhr.onload = function () {
        this.data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
      }
      xhr.send()
    }
  }
})
```

Any help making sense of these errors and helping me understand what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

First: You define the data property as an object literal, instead you should use a function that returns an object literal when executed. For example:

```
...
data: () => ({
    commits: null
}),
...
```

Second: In the function `fetchData`, in the function you assign to `xhr.onload`, it may be that `this` refers to the `xhr` object when `xhr.onload` executes.

Side note: You might want to look up [vue-resource](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource), it's more convenient than using XMLHttpRequest.